# WordPress Multisite - How to backup only 1 child website database (not everything)?

Tags: multisite

I have a WordPress Multisite which includes a Demo website. The demo website database has to be restored hourly to a snapshot.

It's easy to do for the whole Multisite, I just export the whole database as an SQL. How can I export only the specific demo site?

I see that some WordPress tables like Users and Posts are mixed, which seems to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### ID of a site

The data from a site inside a Multisite network are stored in separate tables of the database. Check the ID of the site in your back-end:

> Network --> Websites

Now mouse over, hover effect, about a edit link and you find the ID of the site inside the link `/wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=123`

#### Tables

Each table with this ID inside the name is for this site, like `wp_123_posts`.

#### Plugin hint

It gives also several plugins there have this as solution for easy to use, like 'BackWPup' or similar. The ID of the site is also easier to find with a helping tool. Also, here you should find plugins, like 'Multiste Enhancements'.

### Multisite Only Tables

The following tables are created during the network installation to help manage the network:

- wp_site
- wp_sitemeta
- wp_blogs
- wp_blog_versions
- wp_signups
- wp_registration_log

### Updated tables

The `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables become global across the subsites in the network

### Site specific tables

After the prefix you find the ID if the site inside the table name, like `wp_123_posts`.

- wp_commentmeta
- wp_comments
- wp_links
- wp_options
- wp_postmeta
- wp_posts
- wp_terms
- wp_termmeta
- wp_term_relationships
- wp_term_taxonomy

Comment: Hi Frank. Thank you for the help. Any thoughts on which tables are mixed? For example I see that the users / usermeta table is not unique. Since my plugin deals with user meta, I should backup that as well. Other than that, are there other relevant mixed tables?

Comment: I updated my answer with hints to the tables and his change or is new one. This should helps you.